# Administration of oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I  create tables with user system than I create another user user1 , I give to him all privileges but when I connect with user1 I can't see or select the tables created by system

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never ever create any objects in `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema. Leave them alone, they *own* the database and - if you do something *wrong*, you might destroy the database.

As of your question: "all privileges" is quite broad term. What exactly did you grant to `user1`? You should've - as `system`

```
grant select on table_created_by_system;
```

and then, connected as `user1`,

```
select * from system.table_created_by_system;
```

In other words, you have to precede table name with its owner's name (`system` in this case). Other option is to create a **synonym** (public, perhaps?) and then you don't have to use owner's name.

---

I suggest you abandon it altogether. Drop tables from `system` schema and start over in `user1`'s schema.